# Django: Understanding QuerySet API

Tags: python, django, t-sql

I'm a newbie in Django and I have some questions about making queries by QuerySet API.

For instance, I have User, his Orders, and its Statuses

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()

class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Order(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="orders")
    order_status = models.ForeignKey(OrderStatus, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    creation_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # Some filtering field
    filtering_field = models.IntegerField()
```

I combined all of my questions to this one query:

Get active users with some additional data for each user:

1. 'Amount' of the Orders filtered by 'filtering_field' and aggregated by Min and Max
2. 'Number' and 'Amount' of the first Order filtered by 'filtering_field'
3. Count of the Orders filtered by 'filtering_field', aggregated by Count and grouped by 'Order Status'. This grouping means that data from query #1 and #2 can be duplicated and it's ok.

I could make this query in T-SQL by 3 separated subquery with own grouping, filtering, ordering:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.first_name,
    u.last_name,

    ts.min_amount,
    ts.max_amount,

    first_order.number as first_order_number,
    first_order.amount as first_order_amount,

    cnt.order_status_id,
    cnt.cnt
FROM
    [User] u

    -- 1. 'Amount' of the Orders filtered by 'filtering_field' and aggregated by Min and Max
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            [user_id],
            MIN(amount) min_amount,
            MAX(amount) max_amount
        FROM
            [Order]
        WHERE
            filtering_field = 1
        GROUP BY
            [user_id]
    ) ts ON u.id = ts.[user_id]

    -- 2. 'Number' and 'Amount' of the first Order filtered by 'filtering_field'
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            o.number,
            o.amount
        FROM
            [Order] o
        WHERE
            u.id = o.[user_id] AND
            o.filtering_field = 2
        ORDER BY
            o.creation_datetime

    ) first_order

    -- 3. Count of the Orders filtered by 'filtering_field', aggregated by Count and grouped by 'Order Status'.
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            [user_id],
            order_status_id,
            COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM
            [Order]
        WHERE
            filtering_field = 3
        GROUP BY
            [user_id],
            order_status_id
     ) cnt ON u.id = cnt.[user_id]
 WHERE
    u.is_active = 1
```

How I can do the same by QuerySet API?

Query #1 I can do Min and Max in Annotate.

```
    data = User.objects.filter(
        Q(is_active=True)
    ).values(
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
    ).annotate(

        min_amount=Min(
            'orders__amount', 
            filter=Q(orders__filtering_field=1)
        ),

        max_amount=Max(
            'orders__amount', 
            filter=Q(orders__filtering_field=1)
        )

    )
```

But what about query #2 & #3?

I've considered Subquery(), but It supports the only one output value.
I mean if you wanna get 5 fields from 1 queryset, sql server runs 5 queries. I think it's not good for performance.

How I can join the first order **once** to use its fields and How can I use Count() with grouping by filtered rows of child model?

I'd like to use .prefetch_related() as a substitution of Subquery in T-SQL for each query like this:

```
    Prefetch(
        'orders',
        queryset=Order.objects.filter(filtering_field=1)..., #staff with .values(), annotate(Min(), Max()) and etc.
        to_attr='pf_query_1'
    )
```

And then use 'pf_query_1' like 'orders__pf_query_1__amount' in User.objects...values()...annotate().

But I can't use .values() in Prefetch as well as 'pf_query_1' as a model field.

So what is the best practice to make this one query by QuerySet API?
I'd like to see the whole QuerySet API query just like T-SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the Django `Subquery` as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)?

Regarding your 3rd question the only approach coming to my mind is dynamically creating the annotations.

Here a (tested) code sample using your models:

```
def test_query(self):

        # 1st question
        min_order = Order.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('pk'), filtering_field=1)\
            .order_by().values('user').annotate(min=Min('amount')).values('min')
        max_order = Order.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('pk'), filtering_field=1)\
            .order_by().values('user').annotate(max=Max('amount')).values('max')
        # 2nd question
        first_number = Order.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('pk'), filtering_field=1)\
            .order_by().values('user').annotate(fnumber=F('number')).values('fnumber')
        first_amount = Order.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('pk'), filtering_field=1)\
            .order_by().values('user').annotate(fnumber=F('amount')).values('amount')

        kwargs = {
            'min': Subquery(min_order, output_field=DecimalField()),
            'max': Subquery(max_order, output_field=DecimalField()),
            'first_n': Subquery(first_number, output_field=CharField()),
            'first_a': Subquery(first_amount, output_field=DecimalField())
        }

        # 3rd question
        for o in OrderStatus.objects.all():
            kwargs['%s_count' % o.name] = \
                Subquery(Order.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('pk'), filtering_field=1, order_status=o)\
                    .order_by().values('user').annotate(c=Count('pk')).values('c'), output_field=IntegerField())

        # Putting it all together
        qs2 = User.objects.annotate(**kwargs)

        # Testing the results
        for user in qs2:
            v = Order.objects.filter(user=user, filtering_field=1).aggregate(Min('amount'), Max('amount'))
            self.assertEqual(v['amount__min'], user.min)
            self.assertEqual(v['amount__max'], user.max)
            v = Order.objects.filter(user=user, filtering_field=1).first()
            self.assertEqual(v.number, user.first_n)
            self.assertEqual(v.amount, user.first_a)
            for o in OrderStatus.objects.all():
                v = Order.objects.filter(user=user, filtering_field=1, order_status=o).count()
                if v == 0:
                    v = None
                k = '%s_count' % o.name
                v1 = getattr(user, k)
                self.assertEqual(v, v1)

        # The sql
        print(qs2.query)
```

Please note:

1. The code is part of a TestCase where I put it to check if it worked
   as expected
2. I know some parts of the query can be generated without
   Subquery using the filter attribute of the aggregation functions. As
   this filter attribute was only introduced in Django 2.0 and not
   supported in the LTS version 1.11 I did not use it.

EDIT: Here is another approach I came up with starting with a "base queryset" and annotating that one:

```
def test_query2(self):

        qs = Order.objects.filter(filtering_field=1).values('user', 'order_status').distinct()

        # 1st question
        min_order = Order.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('user'), filtering_field=1)\
            .order_by().values('user').annotate(min=Min('amount')).values('min')
        max_order = Order.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('user'), filtering_field=1)\
            .order_by().values('user').annotate(max=Max('amount')).values('max')

        # 2nd question
        first_number = Order.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('user'), filtering_field=1)\
            .order_by().values('user').annotate(fnumber=F('number')).values('fnumber')
        first_amount = Order.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('user'), filtering_field=1)\
            .order_by().values('user').annotate(fnumber=F('amount')).values('amount')

        # 3rd question
        total_count = Order.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('user'), filtering_field=1, order_status=OuterRef('order_status'))\
            .order_by().values('user').annotate(c=Count('pk')).values('c')

        qs2 = qs.annotate(
            min = Subquery(min_order, output_field=DecimalField()),
            max = Subquery(max_order, output_field=DecimalField()),
            first_n = Subquery(first_number, output_field=CharField()),
            first_a = Subquery(first_amount, output_field=CharField()),
            c = Subquery(total_count, output_field=IntegerField())
        )


        # Testing the results
        for d in qs2:
            v = Order.objects.filter(user=d['user'], filtering_field=1).aggregate(Min('amount'), Max('amount'))
            self.assertEqual(v['amount__min'], d['min'])
            self.assertEqual(v['amount__max'], d['max'])
            v = Order.objects.filter(user=d['user'], filtering_field=1).first()
            self.assertEqual(v.number, d['first_n'])
            self.assertEqual(v.amount, d['first_a'])
            v = Order.objects.filter(user=d['user'], filtering_field=1, order_status=d['order_status']).count()
            self.assertEqual(v, d['c'])

        print(qs2.query)
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply!

I have considered 'Subquery' but I thought it's a bad idea to put a heavy query with grouping, filtering and aggregation in SELECT area, because this query will be runned for each row.
But it seems I've mistaken. MS SQL Server runs such queries just once.

Comment: About 3rd query: It doesn't look what I meant. I don't need every OrderStatus as a single column. I need just two columns: 'order status name' and 'count of orders with this status name' for each user. 
So accordind to this db architecture there will be a duplication of user id, first_name, last_name, min_amount, first_order_number and etc if a user has orders with different statuses.

Like this: 
[
    {
 "user_id": 1,
 ...
 "order_status_name: "pending",
 "order_cnt": 2     
    },
    {
 "user_id": 1,
 ...
 "order_status_name: "approved",
 "order_cnt": 4     
    }
]

Comment: I've checked performance in real db - actually Subquery in SELECT area is slower than Subquery in FROM area (with LEFT JOIN). It affects when you need several columns from subquery. If you need just, for instance, Count(), it's ok. But if you need Count, Max, Min, Avg, MS SQL Server runs 4 queries instead of just one

Comment: Any ideas how can I move this 2 queries with Min() and Max() from SELECT area to 1 query in FROM area like in T-SQL?

Comment: I have added an alternative approach which should deliver the resulting qs you expect. I leave it to you to investigate the performance aspects